# Why is expander designed to hold one content only?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to add few contents to expander however, it throws following error

```
<Expander Name="myExpander" Background="Tan"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="my expander"
              ExpandDirection="Down" IsEnabled="True" Width="100" IsExpanded="True">
        <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="blue"/>
</Expander>
```

**The object 'Expander' already has a child and cannot add 'Rectangle'. 'Expander' can accept only one child.**

I thought I can use Expander as a container holding few elements but it seems it only can hold on to one! any work around?

Thank you.
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the case with many elements.  You would nest a panel, such as a Grid or StackPanel, in order to layout multiple children.

Example:

```
<Expander Name="myExpander" Background="Tan"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="my expander"
              ExpandDirection="Down" IsEnabled="True" Width="100" IsExpanded="True">
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red"/>
            <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="blue"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

This gives you unlimited flexibility on how to layout the children.

Comment: Thanks. I have nested a **<a:myToolbox>** in it which in behind is a `class toolbox : ItemsControl` and also `class ToolboxContent : ContentControl`  now I guess my next challenge is how to add control on it.

Answer (score 2):

`Expander` is a ContentControl, which means it holds a single piece of content.  Most containers are this way.

The way to handle this is to put your rectangles within their own panel, such as a Grid, and make the `Grid` the content of the Expander.

```
<Expander Name="myExpander" Background="Tan"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="my expander"
          ExpandDirection="Down" IsEnabled="True" Width="100" IsExpanded="True">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="blue"/>
    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

You can use any layout mechanism you want here - such as a `Canvas`, `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `WrapPanel`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful nesting an expander in a window where you already have a grid
remember to use Header="texthere" instead of Content=
because the expander content will conflict with the grid content